# Full Text Search on SQL Azure

Tags: .net, t-sql, azure, full-text-search, azure-sql-database

I have a database that I am migrating to SQL Azure. There are a couple of stored procedures in this database that rely on ContainsTable. From my understanding, SQL Azure does not support this. Because of this, I was hoping there would be a way to imitate this functionality in C# code.

Does anyone know how to either: a) Utilize ContainsTable in SQL Azure or b) Imitate it in C# code?

Comment: This book has a code sample for building an index.  Clearly not as extensive Lucene but if you are just looking for Contains type function it might be enough.  http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Windows-Azure-Microsoft-Cloud/dp/0596801971/ref=sr_1_4?ie=UTF8&qid=1339447497&sr=8-4&keywords=azure

Comment: It may be possible to use the new Virtual Machines, just announced last week, and install a full SQL Server instance on that. I believe that would support full text indexing, but you would give up much of the automatic management you get with SQL Azure.

Comment: You might want to check out Azure Search that we announced on Aug 21, 2014 (http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/search/)

Comment: Full text search is now in public preview for SQL Azure. You may want to check the recent announcement here: http://blogs.technet.com/b/dataplatforminsider/archive/2015/04/29/microsoft-announces-azure-sql-database-elastic-database-azure-sql-data-warehouse-azure-data-lake.aspx

Comment: Full-text search is now supported in SQL Azure, here is the link to an example of its advantages, limitations http://www.sqlindepth.com/full-text-search-in-sql-azure/

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, you are right that Contains Table are not supported on SQL Azure as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee336253.aspx).

Based on your question a) is not possible however b) is possible using Lucene.NET.

IF you wish to use code to get full text search in SQL Azure you would need to use Lucene.net in a web or worker role to index your SQL Azure data to Windows Azure Blob storage and then access the indexed data to search. The process is described as below:

1. Configure your Windows Azure Blob Storage
2. Use Web or Worker Role to access you SQL Azure and then create the Index on Windows Azure Blob Storage
3. Use the Indexed data stored at Windows Azure Blob Storage

Here is an article to start your work: [How to Use Lucene.NET with SQL Azure (en-US)](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2367.how-to-use-lucene-net-with-sql-azure-en-us.aspx)

Comment: SQL Azure V12 has full-text search in preview.