# SQL Azure Index performance with like statement

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database

I have a table with a text based column of type `nvarchar(450)` and I created a non-clustered index for that column:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [myindexname] ON [myschema].[mytable] 
(
    [mycolumn] ASC
)
```

My problem occurs when doing queries like:

```
select 
    .... 
where
    .... 
    mycolumn like '%something%'
```

If I try querying without the first %, the index works really fast, but with the initial % it takes large amount of time.

I know that the index basics recommends not using initial % for the where clausules, but I cannot remove it from the queries. I was wondering if there is any option to improve the index (I cannot change the queries right now).

Note: The explain plan shows correct access to the index.

Answer (score 1):

The index is sorted by the column `mycolumn` in alphabetical order. So when you look for a substring with `%` in front, the query engine has to scan the whole table/index.

The only approach to make that kind of queries faster is to use fulltext search.

Comment: Is Fulltext indexing currently supported in SQL Azure?

Comment: Ah yes, you are right. But Lucene.NET seems to be an alternative: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10985596/full-text-search-on-sql-azure

Answer (score 0):

Full text search is now in Preview in SQL DB v12. This perfectly fits in your scenario.